# I am getting an error when using react and redux to get values via my database

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

Here is the error! Displays on the server-side.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

And the front-end component values are also not changed.

Here is the code

```
const [firstName,changeName] = useState("");
    const [username,changeUsername] = useState("");
    const user = useSelector(state => state.User);
    const [id,changeId] = useState(user.id);
    
React.useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get(url+id).then(function(response){
                                   console.log("First Name");
                                   console.log(id);
                                   changeName(response.data[0].first_name);
                           });},[]);
```

There is no error with the get methods. I checked them before implementing this code. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed adding the user state as a dependency to useEffect, your effect won't get an updated value.

**Try this:**

```
const [firstName,changeName] = useState("");
const [username,changeUsername] = useState("");
const user = useSelector(state => state.User);
const [id,changeId] = useState(user.id);

React.useEffect(()=>{
axios.get(url+user.id).then(function(response){
                               console.log("First Name");
                               console.log(id);
                               changeName(response.data[0].first_name);
 });},[user]);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)